# How to stream tweets from private accounts using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, stream, tweepy, monitor

I have been having problems with the MyStreamListener from tweepy, in where I am unable to fetch tweets from private accounts I follow. I know these tweets can be accessed with the API, because I can fetch them with api.user_timeline. Is there any way to be able to stream my whole timeline? Could I just continuously fetch my timeline in a while loop? Thank you for any help!

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''
webhooklink = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
print('starting to monitor!')


class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
    myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
    myStream.filter(
        follow='25073877', is_async=True)
```